# Emulating Wallaby.js test runner

Tags: automated-testing, javascript

Does anyone know of any tools like Wallaby.js, or combinations of various tooling and solutions that would help one achieve a comparable/similar testing workflow, i.e. instant feedbck as you make your coding changes?

btw
*Wallaby.js is an intelligent and super fast test runner for JavaScript that continuously runs your tests. It reports code coverage and other results directly to your code editor, immediately as you change your code. Wallaby.js is insanely fast, because it only executes tests affected by your code changes and runs your tests in parallel. The tool provides a huge productivity boost whether you are doing TDD/BDD or using any other approach.*

Answer (score 1):

Mocha is quite popular https://mochajs.org/

*Mocha is a feature-rich JavaScript test framework running on Node.js and in the browser, making asynchronous testing simple and fun. Mocha tests run serially, allowing for flexible and accurate reporting, while mapping uncaught exceptions to the correct test cases.*

Answer (score 0):

Karma is certainly one option:

https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html

*The main goal for Karma is to bring a productive testing environment to developers. The environment being one where they don't have to set up loads of configurations, but rather a place where developers can just write the code and get instant feedback from their tests. Because getting quick feedback is what makes you productive and creative.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are also doing React you may like https://facebook.github.io/jest/

*Complete and easy to set-up JavaScript testing solution. Works out of the box for any React project.*

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to emulate the integrated testing experience that Wallaby offers, maybe through some sort of IDE integration with TAP?

Comment: My answers were based on the scant information in the question - which I tried to help by ading a bit more instead of closing.  Please put information like that in the question.  I also don't know what TAP is.